Struggling with basic string comparison in bash scripting
So I am starting to learn bash scripting and here is my issue, I have to compare 2 strings and figure out if one of them has more than 113450 and if so, if the var variable contains the elements of the other string. One of my 2 variables (var) is evolving at each iteration. That's pretty straight forward and I thought that I came up with a good solution but it seems like the 2 conditions are never met and nothing gets displayed on the screen, although I know that it's supposed to work.
Here is my code :
#!/bin/bash

var="8dm7KsjU28B7v621Jls"
value="ERmFRMVZ0U2paTlJYTkxDZz09Cg"

for i in {1..40}
do
    var=$(echo "$var" | base64)

    if [ ${#var} -gt 113450 ]; then
        if [[ "$var" =~ *$value ]]; then
            echo -e "Conditions met\n"
            echo "$var" | tail -c 20
            break
        fi
    fi
done


Sorry I did not say that properly, what I am trying to do is see if the variable var contains more than 113450 characters

if [ ${#var} -gt 113450 ]; then         if [ "$var" = "$value" ] So how can var have more characters than 113450 and yet  then still be equal to value which is only ERmFRMVZ0U2paTlJYTkxDZz09Cg, which is way way shorter than 113450 characters?

"${var: -20}" there are not 20 character to offset against -20 - man bash doesn't specify a result in that case.

To understand what the script is doing, put set -x at the beginning so you see all the commands as they're executed, with variables expanded.

Thank you all for your answers and your insightful remarks, I edited the post to correct everything that you pointed, I still don't get anything displayed on stdout though so I don't know if I made something wrong. Unfortunately, set -x is not helping very much since var has a lot of characters.

If you redirect stderr to a file, that might make it easier to parse the set -x results. Also, think about making a shorter/simpler string for testing -- that's appropriate for your question on our site, too, since we want a [mre] to be something we can copy-and-paste to see the same problem, and obviously including a string that's more than 128kb in the question isn't a good use of everyone's time and bandwidth; but if you can solve the problem by checking if it's more than 20 characters long, that's a lot more straightforward to wrangle.

=~ is a regex match, but the *$value is not a valid regex, so [[ always exits with 2. .*$value would be a valid regex.\ Research man 7 glob vs man 7 regex. See bash documentation on [[ https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b .

@KamilCuk: AFIK, it is valid (i.e. not syntactically invalid). It's just that the * at the start, having no element on its left to operate on, is interpreted as literal asterisk. A necessary condition for $var to match would be that it also has an asteris inside.

Hi @user1934428 I disagree. [[ a =~ *a ]] exits with 2 exit code (for me on bash5.2.26). Exit code 2 means error. It is not interpreted as literal asterisk: [[ '*a' =~ *a ]] also exits with 2 exit code. It is a valid syntax, but then when parsing the regex, it fails, and makes [[ always exit with 2 exit code.

@KamilCuk : You are right; I just verified it. I confused it with the behaviour of regex in grep, where grep '*a' <<<'*a' would work, but of course comparing regex in  bash and grep is like comparing apples and pears. BTW, zsh would here even more explicit than bash and report the error message repetition-operator operand invalid.
